# can not add an iframe tab

Tags: iframe, tabs, facebook-apps

Ok, so I've done it a hundred time or more, but today - got a new problem.

1. created a simple html page with an image
2. uploaded to a server
3. opened the page in the browser - no problem, all works fine.
4. created a new app, selected "tab" and insert the tab name, the http and https url
5. Tried to view the app and got "The page you requested was not found"

I've checked with other iframe tabs that I've built, they all configured the same, yet the new one - fails to load.

I've seen that the interface has changed a bit, Its not unusual that Facebook breaks things from time to time but maybe I'm missing something?

Edit: also, from some reason I don't have the "View App Profile Page" on that app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They changed some things around, profile pages are no longer being made.  Check this out http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/

Although I'm still having problems with getting errors when I try to add the app